# How to set default values for shadow property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DB context

```
public class PersonDbContext : DbContext
{
    private static readonly ILoggerFactory
        Logger = LoggerFactory.Create(x => x.AddConsole());

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLoggerFactory(Logger)
            .UseSqlServer(
                "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PersonDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Person>()
            .Property<DateTime>("Created")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Person>()
            .Property<DateTime>("Updated")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    }
}
```

As can be seen from `OnModelCreating` override, I'm adding shadow properties Updated/Created to `Person` entity.

I set those properties to be populated with SQL default values

- `Created` when value is added
- `Updated` when value is added or updated

Below is client code

```
var personId = Guid.Parse("CF5EE27D-C694-408A-9F7B-080FF6315843");

using (var dbContext = new PersonDbContext())
{
    var person = new Person
    {
        Id = personId,
        Name = "New Person"
    };

    dbContext.Add(person);

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

using (var dbContext = new PersonDbContext())
{
    var person = dbContext.Persons.Find(personId);

    var personName = person.Name;

    person.Name = $"{personName} {DateTime.UtcNow}";

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can confirm that both properties are set to UTC date when inserting a new person.
However, on update, `Updated` property is not being set.

This is the t-sql generated:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Persons] SET [Name] = @p0
      WHERE [Id] = @p1;
      SELECT [Updated]
      FROM [Persons]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = @p1;
```

Reading [documentation on genereted value on add or update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-or-update) I see the following warning:

> However, if you specify that a DateTime property is generated on add
>   or update, then you must setup a way for the values to be generated.
>   One way to do this, is to configure a default value of GETDATE() (see
>   Default Values) to generate values for new rows. You could then use a
>   database trigger to generate values during updates (such as the
>   following example trigger).

I don't get what's the purpose of `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` then, if it behaves like `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` and I have to manually intervene (creating a trigger) to set this property.

Indeed, if I change the definition of `Updated` shadow property to

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Person>()
    .Property<DateTime>("Updated")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

And override `SaveChanges` on the `PersonDbContext`

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entity => entity.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        entry.Property("Updated").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This does what is expected.

So the question is - what's the proper way to set default values for shadow properties in EF Core.

This is simplified example from my bigger project, so using `HasData` on the entities in `OnModelCreating` override is not a good option (due to many entities).

I'm using EF Core 3.1.1

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1"/>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13462) will be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [dicussion](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3955#issuecomment-161767967) where it is pointed that name `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` is not descriptive enough.

> @rowanmiller Thanks for the quick reply! Now I know how it works, but
>   I think it's a bit confusing. The naming "ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate"
>   suggests that a value actually is generated on insert and update.
>
> And the docs says: "Value generated on add" "Value generated on add
>   means that if you don’t specify a value, one will be generated for
>   you."
>
> "Value generated on add or update" "Value generated on add or update
>   means that a new value is generated every time the record is saved
>   (insert or update)."
>
> Maybe add a section in the docs that describes how you supply your own
>   value generator?

However, advice [from EF team](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/pull/88#issuecomment-182583905) is to follow the [warning section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-or-update-1) and apply manual steps to [generate values for Update case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-or-update) manually.

> @bcbeatty the detailed explanation is included in the main section,
>   and there is a caution box in the Fluent and Data Annotation sections
>   that points back to the detailed note.
>
> This just lets EF know that values are generated for added entities,
>   it does not guarantee that EF will setup the actual mechanism to
>   generate values. See Value generated on add section for more details.

So it seems, that at least for `DateTime` shadow properties, approach in OP is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have reusable shadow properties follow these steps.

1- create a marker empty interface. `IAuditableEntity.cs`

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// It's a marker interface, in order to make our entities audit-able.
    /// Every entity you mark with this interface, will save audit info to the database.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IAuditableEntity
    { }
```

2- Create a static Class to write your Shadow Properties logic. `AuditableShadowProperties.cs`

```cs
public static class AuditableShadowProperties {

    public static readonly Func<object, DateTimeOffset?> EfPropertyCreatedDateTime =
        entity => EF.Property<DateTimeOffset?> (entity, CreatedDateTime);

    public static readonly string CreatedDateTime = nameof (CreatedDateTime);

    public static readonly Func<object, DateTimeOffset?> EfPropertyModifiedDateTime =
        entity => EF.Property<DateTimeOffset?> (entity, ModifiedDateTime);

    public static readonly string ModifiedDateTime = nameof (ModifiedDateTime);

    public static void AddAuditableShadowProperties (this ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model
                .GetEntityTypes ()
                .Where (e => typeof (IAuditableEntity).IsAssignableFrom (e.ClrType))) {
            modelBuilder.Entity (entityType.ClrType)
                .Property<DateTimeOffset?> (CreatedDateTime);

            modelBuilder.Entity (entityType.ClrType)
                .Property<DateTimeOffset?> (ModifiedDateTime);

        }
    }

    public static void SetAuditableEntityPropertyValues (
        this ChangeTracker changeTracker) {
        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        var modifiedEntries = changeTracker.Entries<IAuditableEntity> ()
            .Where (x => x.State == EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var modifiedEntry in modifiedEntries) {
            modifiedEntry.Property (ModifiedDateTime).CurrentValue = now;
        }

        var addedEntries = changeTracker.Entries<IAuditableEntity> ()
            .Where (x => x.State == EntityState.Added);
        foreach (var addedEntry in addedEntries) {
            addedEntry.Property (CreatedDateTime).CurrentValue = now;
        }
    }
}
```

3- Add neccessery changes to your `PersonDbContext` to use your `IAuditableEntity`.

```cs
 // first we add our shadow properties to the database with next migration
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
...
  builder.AddAuditableShadowProperties();
}

// override saveChanges methods to use our shadow properties.
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            BeforeSaveTriggers();

            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled =
                false; // for performance reasons, to avoid calling DetectChanges() again.
            var result = base.SaveChanges();
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            return result;
        }

     public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            BeforeSaveTriggers();

            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled =
                false; // for performance reasons, to avoid calling DetectChanges() again.
            var result = base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            return result;
        }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            BeforeSaveTriggers();

            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled =
                false; // for performance reasons, to avoid calling DetectChanges() again.
            var result = base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            return result;
        }

        #region "ExtraMethods"

        public T GetShadowPropertyValue<T>(object entity, string propertyName) where T : IConvertible
        {
            var value = this.Entry(entity).Property(propertyName).CurrentValue;
            return value != null ?
                (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) :
                default(T);
        }

        public object GetShadowPropertyValue(object entity, string propertyName)
        {
            return this.Entry(entity).Property(propertyName).CurrentValue;
        }


        private void BeforeSaveTriggers()
        {
            ValidateEntities();
            SetShadowProperties();
        }

        private void ValidateEntities()
        {
            var errors = this.GetValidationErrors();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errors))
            {
                // we can't use constructor injection anymore, because we are using the `AddDbContextPool<>`
                var loggerFactory = this.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
                loggerFactory.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(loggerFactory));
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AppDbContext>();
                logger.LogError(errors);
                throw new InvalidOperationException(errors);
            }
        }

        private void SetShadowProperties()
        {
            ChangeTracker.SetAuditableEntityPropertyValues();
        }
        #endregio
```

**usage:**

4- now you can add `IAuditableEntity` interface to any entity you want to have these shadow properties and you are done.

```cs
public class Person : IAuditableEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using `IAuditableEntity` with a lot of other properties such as `BrowserName` `userIp` ... but I removed those in this example to keep it as simple as possible. it's not easy to explain everything in this example but feel free to ask if you had any questions about this approach.

Comment: Thank you for sharing code. In my specific case adding shadow properties on `OnModelCreating` is enough and no need to define them in interface since _all_ entities should have those properties (Created & Updated).