# The LINQ expression could not be translated using Shadow Properties in MVC Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I've implemented Shadow Properties with a similar approach than the one at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228032/how-to-set-default-values-for-shadow-property). I have a broken LINQ query that was working fine so far with a regular CreatedDate property, now I cannot use it with Shadow Property:

```
    public List<Gastos> GetGastosPorSeleccion(ApplicationDbContext context, int idProveedor, int idContenedor, int idPuerto)
    {
        var gastos = context.Gastos
            .Where(
               item =>
                     (
                     (item.IdProveedor == idProveedor)
                     && (item.IdContenedor == idContenedor)
                     && (item.IdPuerto == idPuerto)
                     )
            )
            .GroupBy(item => item.Tipo)
            .Select(item => item.OrderByDescending(item => EF.Property<DateTime>(item, "CreatedDate"))
            .FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList();

        return gastos;
    }
```

This used to work without using CreatedDate as EF.Property, however, it cannot be translated anymore, nor I can do client-side query as I don't have that property as part of the object.

The query is supposed to filter by some table fields first, then group by type and retrieve the latest record from each grouping.

Here is the exception I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression
> '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (g.Tipo),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Gastos
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False ) )
> .OrderByDescending(item => EF.Property(item, "CreatedDate"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in
> a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

The query works fine at LINQPad6 by rewriting this way:

```
Gastos
    .Where(
       item =>
             (
             (item.IdProveedor == idProveedor)
             && (item.IdContenedor == idContenedor)
             && (item.IdPuerto == idPuerto)
             )
    )
    .GroupBy(item => item.Tipo)
    .Select(item => item.OrderByDescending(item => item.CreatedDate)
    .FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: Which EF version?

Answer (score 0):

The post you showed isn't that accurate in some ways, try to read this article from telerik

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-the-navigation-or-shadow-property-in-entity-framework-core

and you can download the example :

https://github.com/JSGund/ShadowPropertyInEFCore

Suerte Amigo.

--- EDITED

```
public static IQueryable<gastos> GetGastos(this ThisDBContext context, object obj1, object obj2, etc)
{

    var query = from getgastos in context.Gastos
                where item.IdProveedor == idProveedor &&
                      item.IdContenedor == idContenedor &&
                      item.IdPuerto == idPuerto
                orderby EF.Property<DateTime>(item, "CreatedDate")) ascending
                select getgastos;

    return query;
}
```

I believe that can be something like this I didn't put in code just made here.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Jorge! I've seen those articles already, actually, my problem isn't really with how to implement shadow properties but how to perform queries using them. The official documentation shows a pretty elementary case ordering by CreatedDate, when adding more complex query conditions, it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry I can't just used a comment instead of a reply. I can't just comment yet by my points.
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/entity-framework/core/modeling/shadow-properties.md

Comment: or https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Modeling/FluentAPI/ShadowProperty.cs
can you try just  .OrderBy(b => EF.Property<DateTime>(b, "CreatedDate")); instead of Select???
try to make it  IQueryable<Gastos> getGastos(this ThisDBContext dbContext......, , ) Instead of list. then you just return int without ToList.
and call it by
   var query = DbContext.getGastos(.....); ?? with thatyou will separate the layers and find the problem faster.

Comment: It doesn't work as I need a selection field after group by clause: CS1061 'IGrouping<int, Gastos>' does not contain a definition for 'CreatedDate' and no accessible extension method 'CreatedDate' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<int, Gastos>' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference). This error comes from LINQPad.

Comment: And again, if property is not used in GrouoBy - you can not use it in Select later.  You are trying to get Shadow property from IGrouping, which has only Key and can be enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

How it is easy to write non translatable LINQ query using function chain. It does not matter do you use shadow properties or not, query is wrong because group by can return only aggregation result or fields which are used in grouping - not a whole record. It is a SQL limitation and do not expect from EF miracle in such case.

This query can be effectively writen by using Window Functions which are not available in EF (any current versions)

It can be not an answer at all, but if you are OK to use third party extensions [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) - then this query should work:

```
var rnQuery = from getgastos in context.Gastos
              where item.IdProveedor == idProveedor &&
                    item.IdContenedor == idContenedor &&
                    item.IdPuerto == idPuerto,
              select new 
              { 
                 Entity = item, 
                 RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
                    .PartitionBy(item.Tipo)
                    .OrderByDesc(EF.Property<DateTime>(item, "CreatedDate")).ToValue()
              };

var query = from q in rnQuery
            where q.RN == 1
            select q.Entity;

// switch to alternative LINQ translator
var query = query.ToLinqToDB();
```

Comment: you know better. thumbs up.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is an interesting approach, however, I ended up by rolling back to an "Auditable" interface to implement those properties on my model and avoid using EF to retrieve shadow properties.